# What am I missing to make the <li> stay clicked?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-target="#front-info" data-slide-to="0" class="col-md-4 col-width-fix front-info-button">
        <h1>Heading One</h1>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#front-info" data-slide-to="1" class="col-md-4 col-width-fix front-info-button">
        <h1>Heading Two</h1>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#front-info" data-slide-to="2" class="col-md-4 col-width-fix front-info-button">
        <h1>Heading Three</h1>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.front-info-button:hover, .front-info-button:active
{
    background-color:#666;
}
```

It reacts to hover but it won't maintain the color after I've clicked and moved my mouse away. What am I missing?

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ – [what `:active` actually means …](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

Answer (score 0):

You could add that behaviour inside javascript. The example below uses jquery to accomplish this:

css

```
.selected {
    background-color:#666;
}
```

js

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('ul li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

jsfiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/8ZvsF/

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using jQuery:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("dark")
});
```

And the `dark` class:

```
.dark {
    background-color:#666;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6nPu3/

Answer (score 0):

In the event you're not using jQuery, try this JavaScript vanilla solution.

```
for (var i = 0, item = document.body.getElementsByTagName('li'); i < item.length; i++){
(item[i].attachEvent) ? item[i].attachEvent('onclick', function (){
    item[i].className = item[i].class + ' ' + 'active';
}) : item[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.className = this.class + ' ' + 'active';
}, false);
};
```